# Tramp x11 on Mac os (local) , centos (remote)

Tags: osx, tramp, x11

I understand that I should be able to use X11 to show graphs from a remote R when I use a local emacs to connect to the remote machine with tramp.

I have tried a few different things but can not get it to work. I know that the server will work with X11 as if I ssh in using a normal terminal it works.

Currently my `.emacs` file has:

```
;; emacs x11 tramp
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment
              (format "DISPLAY=%s" (getenv "DISPLAY")))


(with-eval-after-load 'tramp
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               '("sshx11"
                 (tramp-login-program        "ssh")
                 (tramp-login-args           (("-l" "%u") ("-p" "%p") ("%c")
                                              ("-e" "none") ("-Y") ("%h"))) ; tried -Y and -X :(
                 (tramp-async-args           (("-q")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-gw-args              (("-o" "GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                              ("-o" "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null")
                                              ("-o" "StrictHostKeyChecking=no")
                                              ("-o" "ForwardX11=yes")))
                 (tramp-default-port         22)))
  (tramp-set-completion-function "sshx11" tramp-completion-function-alist-ssh))
```

On my local machine I also have two files, `config` and `sshd_config` in my `.ssh` folder. The latter simply contains `X11Forwarding yes` whereas the former has `Host my_alias
     Hostname myhost
     User myusername
     ForwardX11 yes
     ForwardX11Trusted yes` (with appropriate subs)

I connect to my server with `C-x C-f sshx11:user@host:/`
I then do `M-x shell` and select the "remote shell path" (to bin bash) and the starting directory.

Now when in the shell if I try `echo $DISPLAY` I get 
`/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zmPeFoMlxA/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

But if I try to load an xprogram such as `xterm` to test I get:
`xterm Xt error: Can't open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zmPeFoMlxA/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Comment: Your X11 forwarding is not getting setup correctly. $DISPLAY should be something like "localhost:3.0", not what appears to be the value of $DISPLAY on your local machine. This works for me here, but I don't mess with tramp-remote-process-environment.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to kind of fix this by running "echo $DISPLAY" in a normal terminal and copying the value of that into the emacs terminal with "export DISPLAY=localhost:12.0" the value does change some times.